# click two radio buttons at the same time?

Tags: html

is there a way by which if i click a radio button(s) in say, FILEA.htm, a corresponding radio button in say, FILEB.htm, is automatically clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that FileA.htm and FileB.htm are independent files, the only way you can do this is if the radio button in FileA sets some persistent value (database, cookie, session variable) that FileB looks at when it gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If FILEB.htm is included in an IFRAME in FILEA.htm, you can do this.